# How to add Glyphicons to my Flask Application without overriding my custom css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am trying to insert some [Glyphicons](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp) to my Flask Web Application.

I added this line to the `<head>` of my template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Here is the `<head>` of my `layout.html` file, which is extended by all views in my web application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- My CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
    <!-- Glyphicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!-- Text in the tab bar -->
    <title>{{ title }}</title>

    <!-- Math formulas -->
    <SCRIPT SRC='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT>MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]}})</SCRIPT>

</head>
```

And I am using, for example, this line in an html file:

```
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>
```

It works, but apparently it overrides my `css` file in the `static` folder, since all the spacing and organizations of views in my site changes. How can I add just the glyphicons I want without overriding my `css` file?

Comment: If bootstrap styling is overriding your styles, I would suggest including the bootstrap stylesheet before your css file... this way your CSS will overwrite bootstraps CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fine with hosting `bootstrap` on your server as opposed to using CDN

1. you can download [customized version of Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/#download) and include only Glyphicon to bootstrap
2. even better just copy glyphicon specific styles to your CSS file and it should work, for example:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
  src: url("/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
  src: url("/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format("svg");
}

.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.glyphicon-asterisk:before {
  content: "\002a";
}

.glyphicon-plus:before {
  content: "\002b";
}

.glyphicon-euro:before,
.glyphicon-eur:before {
  content: "\20ac";
}

.glyphicon-minus:before {
  content: "\2212";
}

.glyphicon-cloud:before {
  content: "\2601";
}

.glyphicon-envelope:before {
  content: "\2709";
}

.glyphicon-pencil:before {
  content: "\270f";
}

.glyphicon-glass:before {
  content: "\e001";
}

.glyphicon-music:before {
  content: "\e002";
}

.glyphicon-search:before {
  content: "\e003";
}

.glyphicon-heart:before {
  content: "\e005";
}

.glyphicon-star:before {
  content: "\e006";
}

.glyphicon-star-empty:before {
  content: "\e007";
}

.glyphicon-user:before {
  content: "\e008";
}

.glyphicon-film:before {
  content: "\e009";
}

.glyphicon-th-large:before {
  content: "\e010";
}

.glyphicon-th:before {
  content: "\e011";
}

.glyphicon-th-list:before {
  content: "\e012";
}

.glyphicon-ok:before {
  content: "\e013";
}

.glyphicon-remove:before {
  content: "\e014";
}

.glyphicon-zoom-in:before {
  content: "\e015";
}

.glyphicon-zoom-out:before {
  content: "\e016";
}

.glyphicon-off:before {
  content: "\e017";
}

.glyphicon-signal:before {
  content: "\e018";
}

.glyphicon-cog:before {
  content: "\e019";
}

.glyphicon-trash:before {
  content: "\e020";
}

.glyphicon-home:before {
  content: "\e021";
}

.glyphicon-file:before {
  content: "\e022";
}

.glyphicon-time:before {
  content: "\e023";
}

.glyphicon-road:before {
  content: "\e024";
}

.glyphicon-download-alt:before {
  content: "\e025";
}

.glyphicon-download:before {
  content: "\e026";
}

.glyphicon-upload:before {
  content: "\e027";
}

.glyphicon-inbox:before {
  content: "\e028";
}

.glyphicon-play-circle:before {
  content: "\e029";
}

.glyphicon-repeat:before {
  content: "\e030";
}

.glyphicon-refresh:before {
  content: "\e031";
}

.glyphicon-list-alt:before {
  content: "\e032";
}

.glyphicon-lock:before {
  content: "\e033";
}

.glyphicon-flag:before {
  content: "\e034";
}

.glyphicon-headphones:before {
  content: "\e035";
}

.glyphicon-volume-off:before {
  content: "\e036";
}

.glyphicon-volume-down:before {
  content: "\e037";
}

.glyphicon-volume-up:before {
  content: "\e038";
}

.glyphicon-qrcode:before {
  content: "\e039";
}

.glyphicon-barcode:before {
  content: "\e040";
}

.glyphicon-tag:before {
  content: "\e041";
}

.glyphicon-tags:before {
  content: "\e042";
}

.glyphicon-book:before {
  content: "\e043";
}

.glyphicon-bookmark:before {
  content: "\e044";
}

.glyphicon-print:before {
  content: "\e045";
}

.glyphicon-camera:before {
  content: "\e046";
}

.glyphicon-font:before {
  content: "\e047";
}

.glyphicon-bold:before {
  content: "\e048";
}

.glyphicon-italic:before {
  content: "\e049";
}

.glyphicon-text-height:before {
  content: "\e050";
}

.glyphicon-text-width:before {
  content: "\e051";
}

.glyphicon-align-left:before {
  content: "\e052";
}

.glyphicon-align-center:before {
  content: "\e053";
}

.glyphicon-align-right:before {
  content: "\e054";
}

.glyphicon-align-justify:before {
  content: "\e055";
}

.glyphicon-list:before {
  content: "\e056";
}

.glyphicon-indent-left:before {
  content: "\e057";
}

.glyphicon-indent-right:before {
  content: "\e058";
}

.glyphicon-facetime-video:before {
  content: "\e059";
}

.glyphicon-picture:before {
  content: "\e060";
}

.glyphicon-map-marker:before {
  content: "\e062";
}

.glyphicon-adjust:before {
  content: "\e063";
}

.glyphicon-tint:before {
  content: "\e064";
}

.glyphicon-edit:before {
  content: "\e065";
}

.glyphicon-share:before {
  content: "\e066";
}

.glyphicon-check:before {
  content: "\e067";
}

.glyphicon-move:before {
  content: "\e068";
}

.glyphicon-step-backward:before {
  content: "\e069";
}

.glyphicon-fast-backward:before {
  content: "\e070";
}

.glyphicon-backward:before {
  content: "\e071";
}

.glyphicon-play:before {
  content: "\e072";
}

.glyphicon-pause:before {
  content: "\e073";
}

.glyphicon-stop:before {
  content: "\e074";
}

.glyphicon-forward:before {
  content: "\e075";
}

.glyphicon-fast-forward:before {
  content: "\e076";
}

.glyphicon-step-forward:before {
  content: "\e077";
}

.glyphicon-eject:before {
  content: "\e078";
}

.glyphicon-chevron-left:before {
  content: "\e079";
}

.glyphicon-chevron-right:before {
  content: "\e080";
}

.glyphicon-plus-sign:before {
  content: "\e081";
}

.glyphicon-minus-sign:before {
  content: "\e082";
}

.glyphicon-remove-sign:before {
  content: "\e083";
}

.glyphicon-ok-sign:before {
  content: "\e084";
}

.glyphicon-question-sign:before {
  content: "\e085";
}

.glyphicon-info-sign:before {
  content: "\e086";
}

.glyphicon-screenshot:before {
  content: "\e087";
}

.glyphicon-remove-circle:before {
  content: "\e088";
}

.glyphicon-ok-circle:before {
  content: "\e089";
}

.glyphicon-ban-circle:before {
  content: "\e090";
}

.glyphicon-arrow-left:before {
  content: "\e091";
}

.glyphicon-arrow-right:before {
  content: "\e092";
}

.glyphicon-arrow-up:before {
  content: "\e093";
}

.glyphicon-arrow-down:before {
  content: "\e094";
}

.glyphicon-share-alt:before {
  content: "\e095";
}

.glyphicon-resize-full:before {
  content: "\e096";
}

.glyphicon-resize-small:before {
  content: "\e097";
}

.glyphicon-exclamation-sign:before {
  content: "\e101";
}

.glyphicon-gift:before {
  content: "\e102";
}

.glyphicon-leaf:before {
  content: "\e103";
}

.glyphicon-fire:before {
  content: "\e104";
}

.glyphicon-eye-open:before {
  content: "\e105";
}

.glyphicon-eye-close:before {
  content: "\e106";
}

.glyphicon-warning-sign:before {
  content: "\e107";
}

.glyphicon-plane:before {
  content: "\e108";
}

.glyphicon-calendar:before {
  content: "\e109";
}

.glyphicon-random:before {
  content: "\e110";
}

.glyphicon-comment:before {
  content: "\e111";
}

.glyphicon-magnet:before {
  content: "\e112";
}

.glyphicon-chevron-up:before {
  content: "\e113";
}

.glyphicon-chevron-down:before {
  content: "\e114";
}

.glyphicon-retweet:before {
  content: "\e115";
}

.glyphicon-shopping-cart:before {
  content: "\e116";
}

.glyphicon-folder-close:before {
  content: "\e117";
}

.glyphicon-folder-open:before {
  content: "\e118";
}

.glyphicon-resize-vertical:before {
  content: "\e119";
}

.glyphicon-resize-horizontal:before {
  content: "\e120";
}

.glyphicon-hdd:before {
  content: "\e121";
}

.glyphicon-bullhorn:before {
  content: "\e122";
}

.glyphicon-bell:before {
  content: "\e123";
}

.glyphicon-certificate:before {
  content: "\e124";
}

.glyphicon-thumbs-up:before {
  content: "\e125";
}

.glyphicon-thumbs-down:before {
  content: "\e126";
}

.glyphicon-hand-right:before {
  content: "\e127";
}

.glyphicon-hand-left:before {
  content: "\e128";
}

.glyphicon-hand-up:before {
  content: "\e129";
}

.glyphicon-hand-down:before {
  content: "\e130";
}

.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right:before {
  content: "\e131";
}

.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left:before {
  content: "\e132";
}

.glyphicon-circle-arrow-up:before {
  content: "\e133";
}

.glyphicon-circle-arrow-down:before {
  content: "\e134";
}

.glyphicon-globe:before {
  content: "\e135";
}

.glyphicon-wrench:before {
  content: "\e136";
}

.glyphicon-tasks:before {
  content: "\e137";
}

.glyphicon-filter:before {
  content: "\e138";
}

.glyphicon-briefcase:before {
  content: "\e139";
}

.glyphicon-fullscreen:before {
  content: "\e140";
}

.glyphicon-dashboard:before {
  content: "\e141";
}

.glyphicon-paperclip:before {
  content: "\e142";
}

.glyphicon-heart-empty:before {
  content: "\e143";
}

.glyphicon-link:before {
  content: "\e144";
}

.glyphicon-phone:before {
  content: "\e145";
}

.glyphicon-pushpin:before {
  content: "\e146";
}

.glyphicon-usd:before {
  content: "\e148";
}

.glyphicon-gbp:before {
  content: "\e149";
}

.glyphicon-sort:before {
  content: "\e150";
}

.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet:before {
  content: "\e151";
}

.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt:before {
  content: "\e152";
}

.glyphicon-sort-by-order:before {
  content: "\e153";
}

.glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt:before {
  content: "\e154";
}

.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes:before {
  content: "\e155";
}

.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt:before {
  content: "\e156";
}

.glyphicon-unchecked:before {
  content: "\e157";
}

.glyphicon-expand:before {
  content: "\e158";
}

.glyphicon-collapse-down:before {
  content: "\e159";
}

.glyphicon-collapse-up:before {
  content: "\e160";
}

.glyphicon-log-in:before {
  content: "\e161";
}

.glyphicon-flash:before {
  content: "\e162";
}

.glyphicon-log-out:before {
  content: "\e163";
}

.glyphicon-new-window:before {
  content: "\e164";
}

.glyphicon-record:before {
  content: "\e165";
}

.glyphicon-save:before {
  content: "\e166";
}

.glyphicon-open:before {
  content: "\e167";
}

.glyphicon-saved:before {
  content: "\e168";
}

.glyphicon-import:before {
  content: "\e169";
}

.glyphicon-export:before {
  content: "\e170";
}

.glyphicon-send:before {
  content: "\e171";
}

.glyphicon-floppy-disk:before {
  content: "\e172";
}

.glyphicon-floppy-saved:before {
  content: "\e173";
}

.glyphicon-floppy-remove:before {
  content: "\e174";
}

.glyphicon-floppy-save:before {
  content: "\e175";
}

.glyphicon-floppy-open:before {
  content: "\e176";
}

.glyphicon-credit-card:before {
  content: "\e177";
}

.glyphicon-transfer:before {
  content: "\e178";
}

.glyphicon-cutlery:before {
  content: "\e179";
}

.glyphicon-header:before {
  content: "\e180";
}

.glyphicon-compressed:before {
  content: "\e181";
}

.glyphicon-earphone:before {
  content: "\e182";
}

.glyphicon-phone-alt:before {
  content: "\e183";
}

.glyphicon-tower:before {
  content: "\e184";
}

.glyphicon-stats:before {
  content: "\e185";
}

.glyphicon-sd-video:before {
  content: "\e186";
}

.glyphicon-hd-video:before {
  content: "\e187";
}

.glyphicon-subtitles:before {
  content: "\e188";
}

.glyphicon-sound-stereo:before {
  content: "\e189";
}

.glyphicon-sound-dolby:before {
  content: "\e190";
}

.glyphicon-sound-5-1:before {
  content: "\e191";
}

.glyphicon-sound-6-1:before {
  content: "\e192";
}

.glyphicon-sound-7-1:before {
  content: "\e193";
}

.glyphicon-copyright-mark:before {
  content: "\e194";
}

.glyphicon-registration-mark:before {
  content: "\e195";
}

.glyphicon-cloud-download:before {
  content: "\e197";
}

.glyphicon-cloud-upload:before {
  content: "\e198";
}

.glyphicon-tree-conifer:before {
  content: "\e199";
}

.glyphicon-tree-deciduous:before {
  content: "\e200";
}

.glyphicon-cd:before {
  content: "\e201";
}

.glyphicon-save-file:before {
  content: "\e202";
}

.glyphicon-open-file:before {
  content: "\e203";
}

.glyphicon-level-up:before {
  content: "\e204";
}

.glyphicon-copy:before {
  content: "\e205";
}

.glyphicon-paste:before {
  content: "\e206";
}

.glyphicon-alert:before {
  content: "\e209";
}

.glyphicon-equalizer:before {
  content: "\e210";
}

.glyphicon-king:before {
  content: "\e211";
}

.glyphicon-queen:before {
  content: "\e212";
}

.glyphicon-pawn:before {
  content: "\e213";
}

.glyphicon-bishop:before {
  content: "\e214";
}

.glyphicon-knight:before {
  content: "\e215";
}

.glyphicon-baby-formula:before {
  content: "\e216";
}

.glyphicon-tent:before {
  content: "\26fa";
}

.glyphicon-blackboard:before {
  content: "\e218";
}

.glyphicon-bed:before {
  content: "\e219";
}

.glyphicon-apple:before {
  content: "\f8ff";
}

.glyphicon-erase:before {
  content: "\e221";
}

.glyphicon-hourglass:before {
  content: "\231b";
}

.glyphicon-lamp:before {
  content: "\e223";
}

.glyphicon-duplicate:before {
  content: "\e224";
}

.glyphicon-piggy-bank:before {
  content: "\e225";
}

.glyphicon-scissors:before {
  content: "\e226";
}

.glyphicon-bitcoin:before {
  content: "\e227";
}

.glyphicon-btc:before {
  content: "\e227";
}

.glyphicon-xbt:before {
  content: "\e227";
}

.glyphicon-yen:before {
  content: "\00a5";
}

.glyphicon-jpy:before {
  content: "\00a5";
}

.glyphicon-ruble:before {
  content: "\20bd";
}

.glyphicon-rub:before {
  content: "\20bd";
}

.glyphicon-scale:before {
  content: "\e230";
}

.glyphicon-ice-lolly:before {
  content: "\e231";
}

.glyphicon-ice-lolly-tasted:before {
  content: "\e232";
}

.glyphicon-education:before {
  content: "\e233";
}

.glyphicon-option-horizontal:before {
  content: "\e234";
}

.glyphicon-option-vertical:before {
  content: "\e235";
}

.glyphicon-menu-hamburger:before {
  content: "\e236";
}

.glyphicon-modal-window:before {
  content: "\e237";
}

.glyphicon-oil:before {
  content: "\e238";
}

.glyphicon-grain:before {
  content: "\e239";
}

.glyphicon-sunglasses:before {
  content: "\e240";
}

.glyphicon-text-size:before {
  content: "\e241";
}

.glyphicon-text-color:before {
  content: "\e242";
}

.glyphicon-text-background:before {
  content: "\e243";
}

.glyphicon-object-align-top:before {
  content: "\e244";
}

.glyphicon-object-align-bottom:before {
  content: "\e245";
}

.glyphicon-object-align-horizontal:before {
  content: "\e246";
}

.glyphicon-object-align-left:before {
  content: "\e247";
}

.glyphicon-object-align-vertical:before {
  content: "\e248";
}

.glyphicon-object-align-right:before {
  content: "\e249";
}

.glyphicon-triangle-right:before {
  content: "\e250";
}

.glyphicon-triangle-left:before {
  content: "\e251";
}

.glyphicon-triangle-bottom:before {
  content: "\e252";
}

.glyphicon-triangle-top:before {
  content: "\e253";
}

.glyphicon-console:before {
  content: "\e254";
}

.glyphicon-superscript:before {
  content: "\e255";
}

.glyphicon-subscript:before {
  content: "\e256";
}

.glyphicon-menu-left:before {
  content: "\e257";
}

.glyphicon-menu-right:before {
  content: "\e258";
}

.glyphicon-menu-down:before {
  content: "\e259";
}

.glyphicon-menu-up:before {
  content: "\e260";
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks to your answer. Can you provide an example with a specific icon? It's not clear for me what part of the CSS should I copy. Thanks!

Comment: @Robb1 did you get a chance to take a look?

Comment: I had to delivery few days ago so I ended up using fontawesome (which I also recommend, if somebody else is interested). By the way I just tested your code and it works exactly as I wanted to: thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your app contain the main template file? If yes, move the bootstrap reference under the main template file instead. This would prevent the overwrite of your custom css.

The below sample should be of help.

**base.html**

```
<html>
<head>
        
<title>{{ title }}</title>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
</head>
<body> 

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

**sample.html**

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
 {% block content %}

<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>

 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! Yes, I have an html template I use for all the views in my site (called `layout.html`). What I was doing was actually adding to the `layout.html` `<head>`,

Comment: I edited the original post inserting the `<head>` of my `layout.html` file, thanks  again for the support!

Comment: @Robb1 that's great :-)